# How to access smart contract functions from React JS?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am making lottery contract , but as I try to access my method of manager I get this error in ReactJS.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Please help me with the solution. I have developed my contract I am having problems with connecting it to the frontend.

This is the error .
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFc2o.png

> App.js File

```js
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";
// import { loadContract } from "./utils/LoadContracts";
import Web3 from "web3";
import lottery from "./lottery";
import {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";

function App() {
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState("");
  const [changedAccount, setChangedAccount] = useState([]);

  const loader = async() => {
    let provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
    let web3 = new Web3(provider);
    return {
      provider,
      web3
    };
  };

  useEffect(async() => {
    let newLoad = await loader();
    let account = await newLoad.web3.eth.getAccounts();
    setChangedAccount(account);
  }, []);

  useEffect(async() => {
    let newLoad = await loader();
    newLoad.provider.on("accountsChanged", function(accounts) {
      let newAccount = accounts;
      if (newAccount) {
        setChangedAccount(newAccount);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(async() => {
    let newLoad = await loader();
    let accountBal =
      changedAccount.length > 0 &&
      (await newLoad.web3.eth.getBalance(changedAccount[0]));
    setBalance(accountBal);
  }, [changedAccount]);

  useEffect(async() => {
    let newLoad = await loader();
    let account = await newLoad.web3.eth.getAccounts();
    setChangedAccount(account);
    const manager = await lottery.methods.manager().call();
  }, []);
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    p >
    Account address {
      changedAccount[0]
    }, Its balance is: {
      balance
    } <
    /p> <
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> lottery.js (containing ABI and contract Address)

```js
import Web3 from "web3";
let web3 = new Web3();
const address = "0xBEbdb8eC68A5803d0f5E93bACe9EB9E4227f5A20";
const abi = [{
    inputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "constructor"
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "manager",
    outputs: [{
      internalType: "address",
      name: "",
      type: "address"
    }],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [{
      internalType: "uint256",
      name: "",
      type: "uint256"
    }],
    name: "players",
    outputs: [{
      internalType: "address",
      name: "",
      type: "address"
    }],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "enter",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "payable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getBalance",
    outputs: [{
      internalType: "uint256",
      name: "",
      type: "uint256"
    }],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "pickWinner",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getPlayers",
    outputs: [{
      internalType: "address[]",
      name: "",
      type: "address[]"
    }],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any 'provider' in lottery.js on this line

```
let web3 = new Web3();
```

which isn't giving you correct contract instance and thus you cannot access it's methods

Comment: I have added but now I am having error execution revert error